# Easy method to remove unnecessary tables/dependencies from a large complex join

Tags: sql-server-2008, join

I have a large complex set of joins in an sql statement (roughly getting 250 fields and using about 80 joins).

I would like to split this large cumbersome query into some smaller ones, say returning only 10 fields each. However, the task of removing all of the joins (which are unnecessary for those 10 fields) is massively time consuming.

Does anyone know of a clever way I could do this in SQL Server? Or is there another tool on the market I could use?

As ever, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I feel for you. And to my knowledge there's no such tool. Yet it's a good candidate for RedGate Refactor.